# NodeJS Route redirection after Login Authorization

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I am working on a NodeJS Application Login. Four routes that relates to this issue are

```
GET /admin/login -- Used to get the Login Page (1)
POST /admin/login -- Used to go to Controller (2)
POST /api/auth/login requireLogin -- Actual login happens here (3)
GET /admin/dashboard requireAuth-- Route to go after successful login (4)
```

**Route Definition:**

```
(1) adminRoutes.get('/admin/login', HomeController.getLoginPage);
(2) adminRoutes.post('/admin/login', AdminController.postLoginPage);
(3) authRoutes.post('/api/auth/login', requireLogin, AuthenticationController.login);
(4) adminRoutes.get('/admin/dashboard', requireAuth, HomeController.index);
```

Values for `requireLogin` and `requireAuth`

```
var requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false, failureRedirect: '/admin/login'}),
    requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local', {session: false});
```

From (1) I fill up login details and hit submit, form action takes it to (2). For (2), I have a method written like this;

**Method for (2)**

```
 exports.postLoginPage = function(req, res, next){
   request.post({url: 'http://localhost:3006/api/auth/login', form: req.body}, function(err, response, body){
     console.log('outside if');
     if(response.statusCode == '200'){
       console.log('inside if 200');
       var wegot = JSON.parse(response.body);
        console.log(wegot.token);
        res.header('Authorization', wegot.token);
       res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');
     }else{
       console.log('if else err');
       req.flash('error', body);
      // return res.redirect('/admin/login');
      return 'Unauthorized';
     }
   })
 }
```

**Method for (3)**

```
function generateToken(user){
    return jwt.sign(user, authConfig.secret, {
        expiresIn: 10080
    });
}

function setUserInfo(request){
    return {
        _id: request._id,
        email: request.email,
        role: request.role
    };
}

exports.login = function(req, res, next){
    var userInfo = setUserInfo(req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
        token: 'JWT ' + generateToken(userInfo),
        user: userInfo
    });
}
```

After successful login from API (3), I need to be redirected to (4). But I am going back to (1). I know login is successful and I am also getting JWT Token on log.

**Log:**

```
POST /api/auth/login 200 32.445 ms - 330
outside if
inside if 200
JWT eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1YTI5MDQ3MGU4Nzc3YTM1OTQ2Mjk5YWEiLCJlbWFpbCI6InNwb25zb3JAZ21haWwuY29tIiwicm9sZSI6Im5pZ2h0IiwiaWF0IjoxNTEyNjQzODM0LCJleHAiOjE1MTI2NTM5MTR9.J5LqkfeSrRU4ukY9rIsFNUBArTLloynRsle4mkwTgpA
POST /admin/login 302 57.531 ms - 76
GET /admin/dashboard 302 2.690 ms - 68
GET /admin/login 200 1.581 ms - -
```

What might be the issue here? How can I solve this. Let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: Can you tell is it a node.js + (ejs/jade) or node.js + angular or what ?

Comment: @Himanshu sharma it a NodeJS Express App, no Jade or Angular.

Comment: @Himanshusharma It is not Angular, it is NodeJs Express App with ES6

Comment: @AnjanaSharma Have a try to this `res.status(200);
res.redirect('/admin/dashboard');` .  This will tell the route the task you send is successful .

Comment: @Himanshusharma Thank you I tried that and now it says, `OK. Redirecting to /admin/dashboard`, but stops there.

Answer (score 0):

> `POST /admin/login 302 57.531 ms - 76
>   GET /admin/dashboard 302 2.690 ms - 68
>   GET /admin/login 200 1.581 ms - -`

Your response status code is 302, which means you have been redirected. Obviously `/admin/dashboard` doesn't accept your authorization token.

Comment: So, what can be the fix?

Comment: How does your dashboard router looks like?

Comment: How does your JWT strategy look like?

Comment: See this https://gist.github.com/luzan/65b1f19f8079c547c034acc96cd90cd5

Comment: Maybe it is the general structure of your app?

Comment: Do you have any good examples of Implementation of Role Based Authorization in NodeJs to share?

Comment: This is a good start if you are into react: https://github.com/vladimirponomarev/authentication-in-react-apps